bibtex from google scholar not working
I have been using bibtex entries imported from scholar, and they worked.
In the file below all 3 references compile and display correctly.  I created the patakitest entry from the pataki2019characterizing entry by


making a copy of the   pataki2019characterizing entry, then
replacing 2019characterizing by test


However, when these are cited  in a bigger latex document, then only the first one displays correctly, for the other two I get a question mark.
So I am not even sure how to generate a proper MWE.
Here is the blg that I get when I compile the bigger document:
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2020)
Capacity: max_strings=200000, hash_size=200000, hash_prime=170003
The top-level auxiliary file: Ram-5-29.aux
The style file: plain.bst
Database file #1: mysdp.bib
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "pataki2022echelon"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "patakitest"
You've used 21 entries,
            2118 wiz_defined-function locations,
            638 strings with 7463 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 6546 in all, are:
= -- 654
> -- 269
< -- 6
+ -- 111
- -- 83
* -- 431
:= -- 1114
add.period$ -- 68
call.type$ -- 21
change.case$ -- 98
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 21
duplicate$ -- 262
empty$ -- 546
format.name$ -- 83
if$ -- 1376
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 21
missing$ -- 21
newline$ -- 108
num.names$ -- 46
pop$ -- 97
preamble$ -- 1
purify$ -- 78
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 165
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 411
swap$ -- 42
text.length$ -- 6
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 78
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 67
width$ -- 23
write$ -- 239
(There were 2 warnings)

Thank you
Here is the main file:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}



\begin{document}
    Some text here
    
    \cite{pataki2019characterizing} \cite{pataki2022echelon} \cite{patakitest} 
    
    
    
        \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{MWE.bib}
    
    
\end{document}

Here is the bibtex called MWE.bib:
@article{pataki2019characterizing,
    title={Characterizing bad semidefinite programs: normal forms and short proofs},
    author={Pataki, G{\'a}bor},
    journal={SIAM Review},
    volume={61},
    number={4},
    pages={839--859},
    year={2019},
    publisher={SIAM}
    }

@article{pataki2022echelon,
title={An echelon form of weakly infeasible semidefinite programs and bad projections of the psd cone},
author={Pataki, Gabor and Touzov, Aleksandr},
journal={Foundations of Computational Mathematics},
pages={1--38},
year={2022},
publisher={Springer}
}

@article{patakitest,
    title={Characterizing bad semidefinite programs: normal forms and short proofs},
    author={Pataki, G{\'a}bor},
    journal={SIAM Review},
    volume={61},
    number={4},     
    pages={839--859},
    year={2019},
    publisher={SIAM}
}


have you re-run bibtex, show the .blg log file from bibtex

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number

you have posted a bibtex log from a different document so it does not help, please post the log showing the output of processing the document posted.

You are missing the closing brace of the first bib entry.
@article{pataki2019characterizing,
    title={Characterizing bad semidefinite programs: normal forms and short proofs},
    author={Pataki, G{\'a}bor},
    journal={SIAM Review},
    volume={61},
    number={4},
    pages={839--859},
    year={2019},
    publisher={SIAM}
} %  <----- this is missing  

Put that brace in; it should work smoothly.

Sorry, my mistake. That closing bracket was actually there in the real bib file, so this is not the issue.

Are you running the compiler (pdflatex or similar) twice? Latex bib compiler is a two pass one. A probably full-proof strategy would be to follow the following recipe: pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex

That link on stack exchange does not help, bc in my case some entries do work and some others do not. Here is the blg file ( I cannot include all of it)This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2020)
Capacity: max_strings=200000, hash_size=200000, hash_prime=170003
The top-level auxiliary file: Ram-5-29.aux
The style file: plain.bst
Database file #1: mysdp.bib
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "pataki2022echelon"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "patakitest"
You've used 21 entries,
2118 wiz_defined-function locations,

I am running texstudio, just click on build and view.

Clicking on that twice or thrice should work. The above MWE correctly works for me after putting the brace in.

Create a separate project in a different folder and check whether this MWE works for you or not.

@district9 don't put logs in comments, as you see it doesn't really work, edit your question to fix the missing } and show the blg you get after running pdflatex then bibtex then pdflatex then pdflatex again

Note Database file #1: mysdp.bib Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "pataki2022echelon" that warning is clearly not from the document posted, so does not help anyone answer your question. @district9

OK, I edited the post. I posted the whole .blg as is.

I am unable to replicate the issue you say you're experiencing if I make your code minimally compilable. Hint: Try changing \bibliography{MWE.bib} to \bibliography{MWE} and perform a full recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more).

@district9 as I commented above you are posting the log from a different document so that is not useful in debugging the issue.

OK, it works now. Thank you for all the help.
